# What NoSQL databases enforce referential integrity at data level?

Tags: nosql

Relational DBs do it with keys and happens at (a **very reassuring**) data level. Document DBs have to enforce it at application level.

RDBs do enforce referential integrity. If a relationship between two people, if one person is deleted, the relationships will automatically cease to exist (I am mentioning ON DELETE CASCADE). If a parent category was deleted, it's subcategories will also cease to exist.

The closest a NoSQL store can come to referential integrity is graph DBs like Neo4j. Here, edges exist directly between two nodes. So, if a node were deleted, the edges will be too.

---

I have been reading up on graph and document stores and I think that NoSQL databases would be making efforts at referential integrity (and graph databases have come close).

Question: Which NoSQL databases have **referential integrity at data level**?

Comment: Similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388051/nosql-rdbms-hybrid

Comment: OrientDB seems a promising candidate

Answer (score 1):

You are right that most of the databases are provide referential integrity at the data level 
but while I am working with [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org) and with MongoDB ORM tool [morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/), morphia provides a mechanism for referential integrity.